# Hello World won't start on iPhone3g

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

So, I've researched and tried around 5 solutions posted here, but the result is this:

The app is fully operational on an iPhone Simulator (inside Xcode)

The app closes as soon as it starts on iPhone (3G, iOS 3.1.3) (the UIView doesn't even load)

Now - this is the solutions I've tried:

- I switched target architecture to "armv6"
- I removed the "Required architecture: "armv7"" dependency
- I'm using iOS 5.1 as Base SDK
- I've put "3.1" as my deployment target
- I've successfully uploaded it via SSH (as a Cydia app)
- When running ldid command I get the following error: "./minimal/mapping.h(54): _assert(false); errno=2"

I'm running out both of ideas and answers on stackoverflow. What am I missing?

Comment: Use debug provisioning and break points

Comment: To see error logs, you need to do it the official way. It's really hard for us to find out what's the problem here. Only thought, disable `Auto Layout`.

Comment: I don't see why it'd work on Simulator if there is any code error. I think the problem is in distribution, more precisely in the signature removing process since ldid posts an error :( Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Had the same problem with my 3gs. My app was to big to handle on the iPhone 3gs. When I test it on the 4 and 4s my app worked. So I think it is a memory issue.

Comment: @NitroNbg `Auto Layout` is not an error. It's a feature that is not available in older versions of iOS. Therefore the app fill crash since it's necessary, unless you disable it. It would've also been helpful if you posted the version of iOS installed on the device.

Comment: As it says in the original question iPhone3G iOS 3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're reaching one of the threshold values for processing or memory usage on iPhone3G. Search Device logs and look for your application name there, you'll get the hint what is causing the problem.